# ADO .NET Entity Data Model: Creating a function

Tags: ado.net

I have search through the web to figure this out but no luck.

I have a Stored Procedure that accepts 10 fields and 3 of them are type OUTPUT so i can return values. I used Function Import to create the function and i put the return type as none. But i can't figure out how to access the function. if I put the return type an entity that i create it is accessible but i get compilation errors that not all fields are mapped.

Comment: well i think my question has been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578536/function-imports-in-entity-model-with-a-non-entity-return-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my question has been answered [Function Imports in Entity Model with a non-Entity Return Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578536/function-imports-in-entity-model-with-a-non-entity-return-type)
it is that the feature has't been created.