# CurrentDateTime() in EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I use this code to get Server Date but I really don't understand.CreateDateTime() is not a sql function.so what is it?

```
DateTime ServerDate = Entities.CreateQuery<DateTime>("CurrentDateTime()").AsEnumerable().First();
```

I think the string that comes in CreateQuery function must be a sql query.Is it wrong?

I have open the SSMS and write CurrentDateTime() and i got an error,I have test this too: SELECT CurrentDateTime(), and i got an error agian,CurrentDateTime() is not a sql function

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ask database server for current datetime using entity framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585272/how-to-ask-database-server-for-current-datetime-using-entity-framework)

Comment: No,I have copy the code from that question but I want to know what is CurrentDateTime.I think you didn't read my question carefully.

Comment: @LightWing: I read your question. Carefully.

Comment: I the question that you have put its link he didn't discuss about CurrentDateTime().

Comment: I have open the SSMS and write CurrentDateTime() and i got an error,I have test this too: SELECT CurrentDateTime(), and i got an error agian,CurrentDateTime() is not a sql function

Comment: That's correct: CurrentDateTime() is not a sql function, its part of EF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CurrentDateTime()` is one of the [Date and Time Canonical Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx) of the Entity SQL.

Comment: And it call GetDate Function?