# Get SQL Server date using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, linq, sql-server-express

In a WCF service I use Linq class. My code is as follows:

```
AttendenceDataContext projectDataContext=new AttendenceDataContext();
var brAttendence = new BR_Attendance()
{
    SupId =1,
    AttenDate=from w in projectDataContext.gete,
    InTime =,
    OutTime =,
    ImageName =,
    ImageUrl =,
    PresentBR =,
    AbsentBR =,
    Active = true
};
```

I write the code in a wcf service can i insert *getsysdatefrom* inside my operation contract method. My wcf service code is as follows:

```
namespace ServiceHost
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [SilverlightFaultBehavior]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class UploadService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public bool Upload(ImageFile image)
        {
            FileStream fileStream = null;
            BinaryWriter writer = null;
            string filePath;

            try
            {
                filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Picture\\" + image.ImageName;
                if (image.ImageName != string.Empty)
                {
                    fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                    writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);
                    writer.Write(image.Imagestream);
                }
                if (fileStream != null)
                    fileStream.Close();
                if (writer != null)
                    writer.Close();

                AttendenceDataContext projectDataContext = new AttendenceDataContext();
                var brAttendence = new BR_Attendance()
                {
                    SupId = 1,
                    AttenDate = from w in projectDataContext.gete,
                    InTime =,
                    OutTime =,
                    ImageName =,
                    ImageUrl =,
                    PresentBR =,
                    AbsentBR =,
                    Active = true
                };

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (fileStream != null)
                    fileStream.Close();
                if (writer != null)
                    writer.Close();
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In *AttenDate* I want to get the microsoft sql server current date. How to get it?

Comment: If you run sql server in same server machine, no issues with DateTime.Now in c# code. Both are same time. Else call a helper sql method that hits database and gives you the time. But we cant tell the difference between the actual time and the output time returned by function.

Comment: SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
GO
SELECT {fn NOW()}
GO
SELECT GETDATE()
GO i want to get datetime directly from linq.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a duplicated question.

If you're using Entity Framework, you could take a look at: [How to ask database server for current datetime using entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585272/how-to-ask-database-server-for-current-datetime-using-entity-framework)

If you're using Linq to Sql, you could take a look at: [How do I use SQL's GETDATE() and DATEADD() in a Linq to SQL expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200617/how-do-i-use-sqls-getdate-and-dateadd-in-a-linq-to-sql-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Write this Code snippet in AttendenceDataContext :

```
Function(Name = "GetDate", IsComposable = true)]
 public System.DateTime GetServerDate()
 {
   return ((System.DateTime)(this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()))).ReturnValue));
 }
```

And Then

```
 AttenDate = AttendenceDataContext.GetServerDate();
```

Comment: I write the br attendence in a operation contract in wcf.can i use the function inside that function?

Comment: You can give it a try !! Write the Code snippet in AttendenceDataContext class.

Comment: where my attendenceDataContext class. i am very new in linq

Comment: Then how are you creating the object? it is a user created class. I don't think this is part of framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Function(Name = "GetDate", IsComposable = true)]
public System.DateTime GetServerDate()
{
    return ((System.DateTime)(this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()))).ReturnValue));
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you did instead of just adding code snippets. That way, the OP (and everybody else) will get a better understanding of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public DateTime getServerTime()
{
    workcalendar2Entities1 db = new workcalendar2Entities1();
    var con = db.Database.Connection;
    var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SYSDATETIME()";
    con.Open();
    var datetime = (DateTime)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();
    return datetime;
}
```

i'm using this which is working with entity framework

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
                using (AttendenceDataContext dboContext = new AttendenceDataContext())
                {
                    var dQuery = dboContext.Database.SqlQuery<DateTime>("SELECT getdate()");
                    return dQuery.AsEnumerable().First();
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
System.DateTime.Now
```

That will return the current date and time.

Have a look at the following page for more information:

[Date Time Now Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.datetime.now.aspx)

Comment: i need sql server current date

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/21/sql-server-retrieve-current-date-time-in-sql-server-current_timestamp-getdate-fn-now/