# Set SQL Server time to Entity Framework CreatedOn column

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I want to fill `CreatedOn` column of my entities. I know the approach of overriding `SaveChanges()` and setting there value, something like this:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var item in ChangeTracker.Entries<ITrackableEntity>().Where(c => c.State == EntityState.Added))
    {
        item.Entity.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}

interface ITrackableEntity
{
    DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I'm setting client side time which is unacceptable in my case (multiuser desktop app, users could have different time on theirs computers). How can I set Sql server time to `CreatedOn` column? I don't want to do this in triggers. I want something that translates into that SQL:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable (Column1, CreatedOn)
VALUES Value1, GETDATE();
```

Comment: You're mixing up `INSERT` and `UPDATE` syntax - you cannot use `INSERT` with `SET .....`. The best place to do this would be a **trigger** - why are you categorically exluding this option??

Comment: @marc_s thanks, I've corrected sql syntax. I believe that trigger is a hidden logic that I want to avoid. And I use database-first approach and don't want to edit my numerous tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How important actual datetime value is ?

If You dont need precisely value You can use :

```
var dQuery =dbContext.CreateQuery<DateTime>("CurrentDateTime() ");
DateTime dbDate = oquery.AsEnumerable().First();
```

**Original link:**
[How to ask database server for current datetime using entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585272/how-to-ask-database-server-for-current-datetime-using-entity-framework)

Comment: Nice workaround but is there any alternatives without extra db querying?

Comment: You can use what @xxMURoXX suggested but for the sake of future readability You can sacrifice one query for keeping business logic in one place imho

Answer (score 0):

Have you alter permissions to the database table. If so you can modify the corresponding column:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
      ...
      CreatedOn DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE())
)
```

Then, after updating your edmx file, you set the corresponding property to ***StoreGeneratedPattern=Computed***. Now you can save your entity without Setting **CreatedOn** in your code. Everything is done by the **SQL-Server**