# Entity Model - Stored Procedure not accessible in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am using Entity Model in Framework 3.5
I have added stored procedure and its functional import. In import function I mapped it to None ( as it doesn't return anything )

I can also map it to a scalar value. But in both cases Its code is not generated.
If I map to an entity then its code is generated.
Why is this? How to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function Imports in Entity Model with a non-Entity Return Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578536/function-imports-in-entity-model-with-a-non-entity-return-type)

Comment: So, EF 3.5 again leaves a bad taste :(

Comment: EF 3.5 does that. Very much a Microsoft 1.0 product. :P